# Adding favorites from a list view to another activity "my favorites "

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view which retrieve the data under each liistview item from parse.com. I want to add a feature of the user selecting his favorite list item and those items getting displayed in another activity which contains all favorites in a list view. I am new to using shared preferences or SQL database. So please can anyone help me ?

Comment: what is contained in a list item? Images ? text? and on which action do you want to show the saved favorite items ? new button click? navigating from home?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana It contains both images and text and it should happen on button for